# Unit testing for rest call

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing

I am currently at a loss with unit testing a method that calls a REST service within it for messaging a status to this service.

I have a method like:

```
public void informService(String state, BusinessObject bus) {

  Client client = null;
  Response response = null;
  try {

    client = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
                            .establishConnectionTimeout(10L, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                            .socketTimeout(10L, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                            .build();

      WebTarget target = client.target("my.url");

      MyDTO dto = new MyDTO();
      dto.state = state;

      response = target.request("application/json").put(Entity.json(dto));

      boolean ok = handleReturnCode(response.getStatus(), bus.getId());

      if (!ok) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid status" + response.getStatus());
      }

      return ok;

  } catch (Exception e) {
  } finally {
    try {
      if (response != null) {
        response.close();
      }
      if (client != null)
        client.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
  }
}
```

So in the method there is a call to a REST service which is evaluated within the method. How can I unit test this behaviour?

Comment: This is really ugly code i must say. To test this you may want to look at PowerMock, it could help you

Comment: The method is not following SOLID principles.  Split the code in resposabilities. Do not build the client in the method, receive it as parameter or use a factory, that way you could mock it and test only the internal logic. Unit tests are about testing method/class logic, not integration with other classes.

Answer (score 3):

When UnitTesting against a network service always move the actual network call into another `Class` and hide it behind an `Interface`.

Then you can create a fake object for that Interface.
In you test you then inject the fake service instead of the real one.

```
//Interface for your service
public interface MyService{
    void sendJson(JsonObject json, Callback callback);

    interface Callback{
        void onResult(int resultCode);
    }
}

//Class you want to test
public void MyClass{
    private MyService myService;

    public MyClass(MyService myService){
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    public void informService(String state, BusinessObject bus) {
         //Do the network call with your service and handle the response
    }

}
```

Now in your test you can create a `FakeService` extending `MyService` and return whatever response code you want to test.
Of course you can also use a mocking framework like Mockito to create your fakes, than you do not have to write them yourself.

Comment: I like the approach, but I a) cannot change the existing code too much and b) I think this is more an integration test.

Comment: @SarahM that doesn't change the fact that the question you asked is about unit tests, not integration tests and there is a world of difference between those two types of test. Its against the site rules to post an answer which does not answer the question asked.

Comment: Excuse me for being vague. I wanted to say that the proposed answer goes more into a integration test direction while I am asking more for a unit test.

Comment: @SarahM No, not at all. The proposed answer is exactly how you should deal with network dependencies on UnitTests. Units (classes) under test should have all their dependencies mocked and injected so you have full control over them

Comment: Hi @SarahM. This answer is correct and is best practice. Keep in mind that unit testing need unit-testable source code. Also one of the main purposes of unit testing is to promote good code.

Comment: Ah! "unit-testable source code" - this summarizes the problem I am having. I am a new (and young) developer facing a huge legacy monster, so I am a bit lost how to deal with that. I cannot just change everything though.

Comment: @SarahM If you have a lot of legacy code read the book "Working with Legacy Code" from Michael C. Feathers. It describes a lot of methods how you can effectively break your dependencies and make code testable. He also describes the method I proposed in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the book recommendation. I will look into it this weekend. I am not sure I can implement it that way without potentially breaking other stuff.

Comment: Thats why you have to be extra careful when breaking dependencies. But getting class after class under test is definitely worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I said about power mock so i write to you what i've written:

Let's say this is your method:

```
public boolean informService(String state) {

        Client client = null;
        client = new ClientBuilder().build(true);

        boolean ok = client.getOK();

        if (!ok) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid status");
        }

        return ok;

}
```

It is easy version of your method, but we still create new Builder here, class is named TestRest. For testing this clearly bad written piece of code we need to use PowerMock:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) //clear
@PrepareForTest(TestRest.class) //clear 
public class TestRestTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnOKWhenOK() throws Exception{

        ClientBuilder builder = PowerMock.createMock(ClientBuilder.class); //prepare ClientBuilder mock to inject while test

        TestRest tested = new TestRest(); //tested class, of course

        PowerMock.expectNew(ClientBuilder.class).andReturn(builder); //What we expect when certain class will be instantiated using new, like in our example Builder

        EasyMock.expect(builder.build(true)).andReturn(new Client(true)); //What we want to obtain, of course you will return some mocked object i think, especially that this is Unit test and you will want to test logic of method, not other classes

        PowerMock.replay(builder, ClientBuilder.class); // change to replay mode to get configured expectation

        assertTrue(tested.informService("state")); //clear

        PowerMock.verify(builder, ClientBuilder.class);
    }

}
```

Also here you have maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-easymock-release-full</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
        <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.8</version>
    </dependency>
```